# Sliding Drawer open from right to left in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

> I am getting issue to open sliding drawer from right to left for
>   xamarin android . but below code working for show sliding
>
> drawer from left to right. if any property of MasterDetailPage  to
>   open sliding from right to left 
>           please share your views with me.  Here Sliding Drawer open from left to right but i want to open from right to left for Xamarin
>   Android
>                           Any idea regarding this. please share your idea's.
>               We are also using MenuRootPage for add items in Sliding Drawer :
>
> ```
>      Code for items view:
> ```

```
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                               >

        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout   BackgroundColor="{StaticResource ToolbarStatusBackgroundColor}"  Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="20">
                <StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{mm:Command SliderClose}" />
                    </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <Image Source="menu.png" HorizontalOptions="Start" Margin="10,40,0,0" />
                </StackLayout>
                <BoxView HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="1000" Color="{StaticResource SeparatorColor}"  />
                <Label Text="My account" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarStatusDescriptionLabel}" Margin="10"  >
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{mm:Command SliderClose}" />
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
                <BoxView HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="1000" Color="{StaticResource SeparatorColor}"  />

                <Label Text="Settings" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarStatusDescriptionLabel}" Margin="10">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{mm:Command SliderClose}" />
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
                <BoxView HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"  HeightRequest="1" WidthRequest="1000" Color="{StaticResource SeparatorColor}"  />

                <Label Text="Logout" Style="{StaticResource ToolbarStatusDescriptionLabel}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Margin="10">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{mm:Command Logout}" />
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>

            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>

        In MenuRootPage .xaml file we are declare master page only UI section
        In MenuRootPage .cs file: here we are inherit MasterDetailPage properties

            Using code:
                     Root page in MenuRootPage .xaml file:
                    <MasterDetailPage  xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                                 x:Class="Ansible.Vektor.App.Shared.Views.MenuRootPage" >
                    </MasterDetailPage> 



                    Root MenuRootPage .cs file:
                    public partial class MenuRootPage : MasterDetailPage
                        {
                            public MenuRootPage ()
                            {
                                InitializeComponent();
                                MasterBehavior = MasterBehavior.Popover;

                            }
                        }



            App.xaml.cs:

             var menuPage = new MenuPages() { BindingContext = MenuPagesViewModel };
                        NavigationPage = new NavigationPage(new MainView() { 
                        BindingContext = MainViewModel });
                        MenuRootPage = new MenuRootPage();
                        MenuRootPage.Master = menuPage;
                        MenuRootPage.Detail = NavigationPage;
                        MenuIsGestureEnabled = false;
                        MainPage = MenuRootPage;


                Here Sliding Drawer open from left to right but i want to open from right to left for Xamarin Android
                Any idea regarding this. please share your idea's.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make custom render for Master Detail Page in Android.

```
public class MyMasterDetailPageRenderer : MasterDetailPageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElement oldElement, VisualElement newElement)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(oldElement, newElement);
        var fieldInfo = GetType().BaseType.GetField("_masterLayout", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        var _masterLayout = (ViewGroup)fieldInfo.GetValue(this);
        var lp = new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(_masterLayout.LayoutParameters);
        lp.Width = 300;
        lp.Gravity = (int)GravityFlags.Right;
        _masterLayout.LayoutParameters = lp;
    }
 }
```